# Why does the Kohen Gadol need to divorce his wife in such a complicated manner?

Tags: marriage, yom-kippur, divorce, conditional-stipulation, masechet-yoma

On Yom Kippur, the Kohen Gadol must be married to exactly one wife. We are also concerned about her passing away.

So the [Gemara](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=13b&format=text) suggests that he gives a get to one wife on condition that the other doesn't die, and to the other on condition that he goes to Shul.

Why not just make a conditional marriage. Give a woman a ring "on condition" that the other wife will pass away on Yom Kippur, and then bring her into the house.

If the wife dies, the Kiddushin will work retroactively, and so will the Nissuin. If she stays alive, then there was no Kiddushin or Nissuin.

Seems much easier and fool proof.

Why didn't they do this instead?

Comment: What about Tosfos ulchada and Yerushalmi: בירושלמי משמע אשה אחרת מתקינין לו מזמנין אותה שאם תמות אשתו ביום הכפורים שיקדש זאת ביוה"כ ופליג אגמרא דידן דפריך התם ויקדש מאתמול דמשמע ליה מתקינין בהזמנה בעלמא

Comment: The Problem is kinyan on shabbas, see Tosfos

Comment: BTW: AFAIK this is all theoretical, as we do not pasken that he has to prepare for his wife's demise. So  _We are also concerned about her passing away._ is inaccurate. but the question is still an interesting one, on a theoretical level.